# String being cut short of two chars

Tags: c, string

I need to get a user-input string with a maximum length of 50 chars. Therefore I defined a `MAX_STRING_LENGTH` variable at 50 and the string is initalized with 51 characters. However, every time the input is greater than 48 characters, the string is cut from the last two characters. This is a school exercise and I can't use `<string.h>`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 50

int main(void) 
{   
    int j=0;

    char stringInput[MAX_STRING_LENGTH+1]; //string initialized.
    printf("Please enter a valid string\n");
    fgets(stringInput,MAX_STRING_LENGTH,stdin); //string input.

    for(j=0;stringInput[j]!='\0';j++);
    if(j<MAX_STRING_LENGTH+1)
    {
        j=j-1;
        stringInput[j]='\0'; //remove newline if it exists
    }  
    //...
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why the string is losing 2 characters.

I am assuming that a newline(`\n`) is created always when using `fgets` (even if a full string of 50 characters is inputted), and  I'm losing 1 character always(and therefore I have to increase the string size of the string). However I do not understand how the other character is lost.

I would appreciate your feedback. Thank you

Comment: Read the documentation for `fgets` carefully. It always stores a null terminator, so it reads one less character than the size you pass it, so you can never read 50 chars (because it will only read 49, then store a null). You claim to remove a newline "if it exists" but always remove it unconditionally, even when the last character is not a new line - stop doing that. Why have you re-implemented `strlen` by hand?

Comment: So if you input 49 characters, do you get 47? or 46?

Comment: How can you initialize a *character array* of 50 with 51 values (per the 2nd sentence of your question)?

Comment: Life would be a lot easier if you used `std::string` and `std::getline`.  The `getline` function does not store *newline*.

Comment: Why is this tagged C++? This is clearly C code.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews He's using the wrong word, he apparently meant that he declares it with 51 characters -- `[MAX_STRING_LENGTH+1]`

Answer (score 0):

In this call

```
fgets(stringInput,MAX_STRING_LENGTH,stdin);
```

you specified that at most `MAX_STRING_LENGTH - 1` characters will be read in the array `stringInput`.

If you want that the array can contain a string with 50 characters (excluding the terminating zero) then you have to call `fgets` like

```
fgets(stringInput,MAX_STRING_LENGTH + 1,stdin);
```

But in this case the new line character that corresponds to the entered key Enter will still be in the input buffer if the user entered exactly 50 characters. To extract it you should declare the array at least like

```
char stringInput[MAX_STRING_LENGTH + 2];
```

and write the call like

```
fgets(stringInput,MAX_STRING_LENGTH + 2,stdin);
```

However it would be better initially to declare `MAX_STRING_LENGTH` equal to 52.

Answer (score 0):

this little loop

```
   for(j=0;stringInput[j]!='\0';j++);
    if(j<MAX_STRING_LENGTH+1)
    {
        j=j-1;
        stringInput[j]='\0'; //remove newline if it exists
    }
```

removes the last character regardless of what it contains.

Answer (score -1):

This is a [c] not a [c++] question.

Documentation for [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/)